College Scorecard earnings by field of study
Are earnings by field of study (EARN_MDN_5YR) from Treasury/IRS or institution-reported? The glossary (https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/glossary/) states that those data are from institutions, but the data dictionary (https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/) says that the data source is Treasury. Thank you.
